# Wildcards for listening scope broadcasts with $on on AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to capture scope broadcasts using wildcards on AngularJS?

Example:

`$rootScope.$on('*created', function () {
    // do stuff
});`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the angular js source code, `$on` is defined as follows:

```
$on: function(name, listener) {
   var namedListeners = this.$$listeners[name];
   if (!namedListeners) {
      this.$$listeners[name] = namedListeners = [];
   }
   namedListeners.push(listener);

   return function() {
     namedListeners[indexOf(namedListeners, listener)] = null;
   };
},
```

since `this.$$listeners` is an associative array, and associative arrays in javascript do not take regexs as keys, this suggests that the short answer is "no you can not".

Comment: Yeah, that's what I though. It would be cool to have, though.
I' trying to make a "smart notifying" for messages about success/failure of creation of entities. Now I'm digging through ngResource code to see if I can hookup something on the resource `$save`/`$get` and so methods.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box, but.. You could create a helper function customOn() and use that instead of $on. customOn() could execute a regex on the event name and dispatch whatever event.